# Gif crashes script when followed by input statement

Tags: python, pyglet

Im trying to print a gif in my homework game if someone wins or loses, and for that I have this code:

```
import shutil
import pyglet
import requests
import os

def gif():
    url = 'https://tenor.com/view/no-oh-no-nope-nah-not-really-gif-15162749.gif'
    filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    with open(filename, 'wb') as out_file:
        out_file.write(requests.get(url).content)
    os.rename('no-oh-no-nope-nah-not-really-gif-15162749.gif', 'michaelscott1.gif')

    animation = pyglet.image.load_animation('michaelscott1.gif')
    animSprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(animation)

    w = animSprite.width
    h = animSprite.height

    window = pyglet.window.Window(width=w, height=h)

    @window.event
    def on_draw():
        window.clear()
        animSprite.draw()

    pyglet.app.run()

gif()
```

If I run it the program it shows the gif, and when I close it, the program finishes with exit code 0.

If I put a print statement after it, it shows the gif, prints the print and then finishes with exit code 0.

But if I try to make an input statement after the gif

```
input('>')
```

The python window showing the gif crashes. And when I force close it, the script quits, and I get this return statement:

```
Process finished with exit code 143 (interrupted by signal 15: SIGTERM)
```

What is the solution to this?

Comment: Just a pro-tip: Don't use Python2. Switch to Python3 and just ignore every example that touches Python2. `input()` in this case does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you switch to Python3 *(which you should)*, things might start to work a little bit better.
Some improvements if nothing else to the code, would be to not store the image on disk unless you really need to.

You can circumvent this by using `io.BytesIO` and load the image from within memory:

```
import pyglet
import os
import urllib.request, io

def url_to_sprite(url):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
        image_data = response.read()

    image = pyglet.image.load_animation(os.path.basename(url), file=io.BytesIO(image_data))
    return pyglet.sprite.Sprite(image)

animSprite = url_to_sprite('https://media.giphy.com/media/13gvXfEVlxQjDO/giphy.gif')
input('>')
window = pyglet.window.Window(width=animSprite.width, height=animSprite.height) 

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    animSprite.draw()

pyglet.app.run()
```

I can't reproduce any errors with this code. And nothing crashes when using the input.
The program will however not render anything until after the input is completed.